# Tomcat 6, JBoss EL2.2 and MyFaces: MyFaces Unified EL support disabled

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2, el, myfaces

my problem:
I have an application running on Tomact 6 with JBoss EL2.2 and MyFaces 2.1.6. The JBoss EL 2.2 lib is provided by the war and no EL libs were removed from the original tomcat installation.
Now I get the error **MyFaces Unified EL support disabled** since I guess myfaces doesn't recognize my setup is **EL 2.2 ready**. Using Mojarra works fine.

There was a similar question before, but no solution:
[How can I update Websphere 7 to use EL2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091354/how-can-i-update-websphere-7-to-use-el2-2)

Any suggestions, how I could tell MyFaces I'm EL 2.2 ready?

Thanks
Jonny